# Multiple IF Then results into one textbox

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, textbox, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007 VB, is it possible combine the results of multiple `If Then` statements into one textbox?  This code produces three results but I need the three combined into `txtLOB` at the end.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

    If CSBB <> "No Impact" Then
        txtCSBB = "CSSB"
    End If

    If HL <> "No Impact" Then
        txtHL = "HL"
    End If

    If GWIM <> "No Impact" Then
        txtGWIM = "GWIM"
    End If

    txtLOB.Text = txtCSSB.Text & txtHL.Text & txtGWIM.Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to avoid the extra three textboxes, try this:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Dim sText As String

    If CSBB <> "No Impact" Then
        sText = "CSSB"
    End If
    If HL <> "No Impact" Then
        sText = sText & "HL"
    End If
    If GWIM <> "No Impact" Then
        sText = sText & "GWIM"
    End If

    txtLOB = sText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Yess, it is. Skip 'text'

```
txtLOB = txtCSSB & txtHL & txtGWIM
```

If these are the names of textboxes on the form for which this is the module, best use Me:

```
Me.txtLob
```

You can only use the .text property for the textbox that has the focus, and it refers to the current contents, not necessarily the same as the .value property.